# Does changing Item-Level-Permission trigger ItemUpdated/ItemUpdating in Event Receiver?

Tags: workflow, permissions, event-receivers

First of all: I know that setting item-level-permissions are bad :)

I just wonder: When I created an Event-Receiver that set per-item-Permissions on the ItemAdding-Event:

Will this trigger the ItemUpdating-Event? Or does that only gets triggered when the "pure" item is modified?

The same question to workflows: Do creating/modifying workflows do trigger events on the connected item?

(PS: I know the EventFiringEnabled - Property to prevent this if needed)

Comment: Good question. I'm too eager to know its answer! :-)

Comment: If you know about EventFiringEnabled, where is the problem? Set it to false and the event won't be fired

Comment: This is not about solving a coding problem, but about knowledge. I want to understand how SP works there (and if EventFiringEnabled is even needed in this case)